# dwr - upload file and download file in one request

Tags: java, dwr

is it possible to upload a file and subsequently when receiving response download the file,

I mean in one request I'll upload a file and download the file in one action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It's possible to do that at least in dwr 3.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this demo code will be helpful for you: 
http://directwebremoting.org/dwr-demo/simple/download.html

Answer (score 0):

An example which return a excel to download from client:

//Java side:

```
public FileTransfer getExcel(Parametros param){
   byte[] result = <here get data>;
   InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result); 
   String excelFormat = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
   FileTransfer dwrExcelFile = new FileTransfer("excel.xlsx", excelFormat, myInputStream);
   return dwrExcelFile;
}
```

//Javascript side:

```
function downloadExcelFile() {
  dwr.engine.setTimeout(59000);
  var params = <params_to_send>;
  <Java_class>.getExcel(params, {callback:function(dataFromServer) {
    downloadExcelCallback(dataFromServer);
  }});
}

function downloadExcelCallback(data) {
   dwr.engine.openInDownload(data);
}
```